# Admin Grid Pull Data From Different Table

Tags: admin, grid

I have a grid in admin set up like so:

[image]

It's pulling data from MySQL table "party."

I'd like the column called "Real Party ID" to pull its value from another table, "foobar"

How can I achieve this result?

Let me know if you need more details or pieces of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage :: getModel('module/module')->getCollection();

    $collection->getSelect()
          ->join(array('alise' => $collection->getTableName('foobar/foobar'))  ,'main_table.entity_id = alise.entity_id', array('party_name' => 'name'));
  $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
 }
```

try this code in your `module/block/adminhtml/module/grid.php`

Comment: Thanks! This works great for me.  I'd upvote the answer if I had enough reputation :)

For anyone interested, here is the code I ended up using:

`$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('party_details' => 'party_details'), 'main_table.party_id = party_details.partyid', array('party_real_id' => 'partyid'));`